# openCamera in AsyncTask returns "IllegalArgumentException"

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera2

I am trying to create an *AsyncTask* which will take pictures in background, but I am receiving

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Handler argument is null, but no looper exists in the calling thread

In the **doInBackgroung** method I've got:

```
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    startBackgroundThread();
    openCamera();
    takePicture();
    return "Executed";
}
```

and then in the **openCamera** method:

```
private void openCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try{
        cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        assert map != null;
        imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];

        manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null); //It is breaking here

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion how can I solve this ?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that the application works fine when I am using just a normal Activity, but now I want to move that camera code into and AsyncTask, so it runs in background.

Comment: Do not call those three functions from the doinbackground function.

Comment: @greenapps Then how to do it ? I am very new to Android development so I would appreciate it if you could advice me how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is intended to be used for short lived operations and doesn't use a `Looper` internally, which is needed for the camera APIs. A `HandlerThread` could be used instead, or a `Thread` where you manage the `Looper` yourself.

You'll likely run into other power management related issues with Android M+ when using a background thread, though. There are limits put on background operations in order to conserve battery life. Be sure you need to use the camera in the background.

Comment: So basically the first time I tried with IntentService, and I had a problem with this as wel - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768663/take-a-photo-with-camera2-using-intentservice. According to your suggestion shall I convert my whole CameraService.java code to an HandlerThread? And yes I really need my camera in background

Comment: You could use a handler thread in a service. An `IntentService` would have problems since as soon as the `Intent` handler finishes, the service destroys itself.